# Getting an error when trying to make a basic SMTP email send and receiver

Tags: java, eclipse, email

I'm trying to create a program that will send and receive emails, and my code is almost a replica of code from two pages that I've seen, but it produces an error when theirs doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Properties p = new Properties();        
        //p = System.getProperties();

        Session s = Session.getInstance(p,null);


        try
        {
            Message m = new MimeMessage(s);
            m.setFrom(new InternetAddress("....adress...."));
            m.setRecipients(m.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("....adress...."));

            Transport.send(m);
        }
        catch (MessagingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

I get the error on the setRecipients line specifically on the word RecipientType, and it says "RecipientType cannot be resolved or is not a field". I've checked the formatting but nothing seems wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: We can't see your screen. You need to give the text of the error.

Comment: I did. The error is the words in the quotation marks.

Comment: Oh hey, you did. my apologies.

Comment: add the full stacktrace please

Answer (score 0):

RecipientType is a static inner class as far as i can tell. (see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.RecipientType.html )

afaik those need to be accessed via class name:

```
m.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("....adress...."));
```

after that in launched fine for me. (and threw an exception because ....address wasnt connecting, but thats besides the point)